# What is the zero signal?

Tags: linux, unix, signals, nagios

I was looking into a nagios plugin and I found this code:

```
killall -0 $1
```

I tried this and it returned `0` for a running process, but it did not kill the process.

Please explain the meaning of this `0` value and why it did not kill the process.

Answer (score 10):

From `man 2 kill`:

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still
>   performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID
>   or process group ID.

`kill(2)` returns `0` on success, and `-1` otherwise. So, with the zero signal, assuming that the process has enough permission to send a signal to the target process, `0` is returned if the process or process group ID exists, otherwise, it returns `-1` (and sets `errno` to `ESRCH`). Note that the man page simply states that *error checking is still performed*, so it will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EPERM` if the target process exists but the sending process does not have enough permissions to send it a signal.

The `killall(1)` and `kill(1)` command utilities behave similarly because they use `kill(2)` under the hood.

Note that program code should not rely on this to make decisions based on the existence of a process: there is always a window of time between checking that the process exists and using that information where the process could terminate (and possibly a new, unrelated process starts in that window of time and the same PID is recycled and used).

Answer (score 2):

signal `-0`just checks to see if the specified process is running.  It doesn't kill it.  If you want to kill the process use `-9` which is a termination signal.

While `-0` isn't listed here, this link explains what some of the other signals are:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: It is seldom a good idea to kill a process with `SIGKILL` (signal 9), because the process has no chance to do any cleanup before terminating.  That should only be used as a last resort when neither `SIGINT` nor `SIGTERM` seem to work.